# Class serialization in simple program, should I worry about it?

Tags: java

Im working on a very simple project in java that utilizes the Swing component
and I have a class that when finished with all its statements, Eclipse underlines it with a yellow line and gives the warning "The serializable class HelloComponent does not declare a static final serialVersionUID of type long"

The program works fine but whenever i create any classes other than the main one, I get this warning... Should I worry about it for now? Im a beginner in java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use the serialVersionUID or suppress warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146715/use-the-serialversionuid-or-suppress-warnings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely ignore it if you are not going to do any serialization. However depending on what your application does... other frameworks / libraries may require serialization to work probably. (Ie object saving, remote procedure calls, database interaction.)

When in doubt just have ecilpse auto create it.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not doing any object serialization, you can ignore this warning.

(Even if it does, the application will still work.  It is just that serialization will be more fragile in the face of changes to the classes that are being serialized.)

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over it Eclipse should be giving you the option to create it for you.  You might as well select that option and let Eclipse fill it in for you.

There are some guidelines you can read at [Java Practices -> Implementing Serializable](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45).

Answer (score 0):

The warning is only applicable if your application is going to serialise the objects, and store the data persistently. It makes very little sense to serialise Swing components.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others people, if your application will not do any serialization, you can ignore the warning.

Eclipse can help you to generate a `serialVersionUid` attribute. Otherwise, you can annotate your class by a `@SuppressWarnings("serial");`