# Java serializeable warning when not overloading attribute

Tags: java, interface, serializable

How does the java compiler warn you about not declaring a `serialVersionUID` uid field? Is there a way I can do that for a custom interface or is that java language magic?

Edit:

My question isn't so much about the serializable interface, I understand that. But how does it generate the warning? I want to implement the same thing (warn if classes implementing my interface don't provide a certain attribute) but I don't see anything on how serializable does it.

Answer (score 2):

It won't warn you, it will just generate `serialVersionUID` for you silently. Most IDEs however will trigger warnings for `Serializable` classes without this field (for a reason).

See also: [Use the serialVersionUID or suppress warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146715)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your asking. It's a feature of the Serializable interface, I think combined with Eclipse's code style options (or whatever IDE you're using), that generates this warning. If you check under code style options (which generally give you a number of warning you an turn on, so the IDE can help you keep your code clean), I think you'll find the option that generates this warning.

The purpose of the warning, in case you're wondering, is that the serialVersionUID is used to uniquely identify a serialized object. When your code tries to de-serialize that object (say, from a file), if you're using the standard serialization techniques in Java, the JVM will throw an error when the serialVerionUID for the class you're trying to de-serialize, doesn't match the one in the complied class file. It one way of the JVM loading a serialized object that contains a previous/alternate version of the given object/data structure.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say, the warning you are looking for is highly specific to `Serializable`.

In general, an interface cannot specify what fields should exist in classes that implement it.  This is actually basic OO design - a field is implementation, not interface.

For your need, perhaps it would be better to have a method in the interface, `getTheField()`.  Classes implementing the interface would then be required to implement that method.  They may or may not do so by using a private field to store the data, but that seems like an internal implementation detail that should not matter to the callers.