# warning: [serial] serializable class SomeClass has no definition of serialVersionUID

Tags: java, netbeans

Eventhough this class is not intended ot set to be serializable, I'm getting this unusual warning! Could someone let me know if you have come across such odd warning?!

```
C:\Documents and Settings\...filename.java:60: warning: [serial] serializable class SomeClass has no definition of serialVersionUID
public class NewPortalConnection extends javax.swing.JFrame {
```

Regards

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This warning comes when you derive from a class that implements  Serializable. In your case, the Serializable parent class is JFrame.

You can suppress this warning with @SuppressWarnings("serial"), or give the class a serialVersionUID: `private static final long serialVersionUID = ...;` (with a long value for the dots).

There is a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146715/use-the-serialversionuid-or-suppress-warnings) here on SO on which is preferable.

Comment: So what do you think I should to do to get rid of this warning??!

Comment: I have added your options to the answer.

Comment: Thanks S.L. Barth for the accurate and spot on answer!  You saved me a lot of hasstle!  All the best!

Comment: Is there any recommended way to derive the unique value?

Comment: @KevinCox Not sure what is recommended, but the Eclipse IDE has an option "Add generated serial Version ID".

Answer (score 7):

[`JFrame`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) implements Serializable, so all extending classes also implement Serializable.

Here's a tutorial [about Serializable and serialVersionUID](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45), but to really understand the topic you should read Chapter 11 of [Effective Java (2nd Ed) by Joshua Bloch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

Comment: I will definitely read the suggested papers!  Thank you Sean!

Answer (score 7):

If you know your application never serializes things, add `-Xlint:-serial` to command line arguments of `javac`. For example,

`javac -Xlint -Xlint:-serial *****`

This way you will have all warnings except "serial".

Comment: Is there any way to except serial for one folder?

Comment: @doN I don't know (except multi-stage javac invocation for different folders). I'm not working with java normally anyway, only Scala or Rust, so I'm no expert in these things.

Comment: Looks like i have to deepdive on the documentation:)